# How to use result of first join in second join in LINQ to SQL

Tags: c#, sql, linq, linq-to-sql

I have list table with 2 record. List A and List B. List A has 4 tasks in Task table and List B has 2 tasks in Task table. Task 1 of List A has two time log entries in TimeLog table.No foreign key used.

Now Consider the following code.

```
var objs = from project_task_list in modelRepository.Get()
                       join project_task in projectTaskRepository.Get() on project_task_list.ListId equals project_task.ListId into project_task_result
                       join project_task_timelog in projectTaskTimeLogRepository.Get() on project_task.TaskId equals project_task_timelog.TaskId into project_task_timelog_result
                       where project_task_list.ProjectId == project_id
                       select new ProjectTaskListModel
                       {
                           ListId = project_task_list.ListId,
                           ProjectId = project_task_list.ProjectId ?? 0,
                           ListName = project_task_list.ListName,
                           ListStartDate = project_task_list.ListStartDate,
                           ListEndDate = project_task_list.ListEndDate,
                           ListStatusId = project_task_list.ListStatusId ?? 0,
                           ListSortOrder = project_task_list.ListSortOrder ?? 0,

                           ListTasksEstimatedHours = project_task_result.Sum(x => x.TaskEstimatedHours) ?? 0,
                           ListTasksTimeLogTotalMinutes = project_task_timelog_result.Sum(x => x.LogMinutes) ?? 0
                       };
```

I want to use result of one join in another join but i am having following syntax error.

[image]

I have also tried the following code.

```
var objs = from project_task_list in modelRepository.Get()
                       join project_task in projectTaskRepository.Get() on project_task_list.ListId equals project_task.ListId into project_task_result
                       from project_task in project_task_result.DefaultIfEmpty()
                       join project_task_timelog in projectTaskTimeLogRepository.Get() on project_task.TaskId equals project_task_timelog.TaskId into project_task_timelog_result
                       where project_task_list.ProjectId == project_id
                       select new ProjectTaskListModel
                       {
                           ListId = project_task_list.ListId,
                           ProjectId = project_task_list.ProjectId ?? 0,
                           ListName = project_task_list.ListName,
                           ListStartDate = project_task_list.ListStartDate,
                           ListEndDate = project_task_list.ListEndDate,
                           ListStatusId = project_task_list.ListStatusId ?? 0,
                           ListSortOrder = project_task_list.ListSortOrder ?? 0,

                           ListTasksEstimatedHours = project_task_result.Sum(x => x.TaskEstimatedHours) ?? 0,
                           ListTasksTimeLogTotalMinutes = project_task_timelog_result.Sum(x => x.LogMinutes) ?? 0
                       };
```

Syntax error gone but the problem is it is returning 6 records while i only have 2 records in list table. What am i doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: One question per post please. Note however, that performance questions tend to be unanswerable. Let alone when we know nothing of the data and the architecture.

Comment: @GertArnold This is not a performance question nor two questions. This is a one simple question that i am not able get desire result from LINQ query i posted. I have showed that what i have already tried. I will try to post some sample data but i don't think it will help much.

Comment: Once you do an `into`, the range variable for the `join` is no longer in scope - it has been absorbed by the `into`.

Comment: Thanks @NetMage. Yes i understand this and if you look at the last code block i posted, i have used a from clause from the result of join and syntax error gone away but now the result contain rows from both list and task table and this is what i am not able fix.

Comment: The second `from` essentially creates a result entry for every task row that matches, if you don't want that you need to change the priority of your `join`s. Do you only want Task1 of List A or do you want the tasks that have no time entries as well?

Comment: @NetMage I need all the records from list table with two additional columns ListTasksEstimatedHours and ListTasksTimeLogTotalMinutes. First column will be SUM of all tasks estimate (this column is in task table) belong to particular list. Second column will be SUM of time logs (Time logs are stored in seperate time log table against task_id) of all the tasks that belong to particular list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured it out my self. All i need was GROUP BY clause in LINQ. Here is the final query.

```
var objs = from project_task_list in modelRepository.Get()
                       join project_task in projectTaskRepository.Get() on project_task_list.ListId equals project_task.ListId into project_task_result
                       from project_task in project_task_result.DefaultIfEmpty()
                       join project_task_timelog in projectTaskTimeLogRepository.Get() on project_task.TaskId equals project_task_timelog.TaskId into project_task_timelog_result
                       from project_task_timelog in project_task_timelog_result.DefaultIfEmpty()
                       where project_task_list.ProjectId == project_id

                       group new { project_task_list, project_task, project_task_timelog } by new
                       {
                           project_task_list.ListId,
                           project_task_list.ProjectId,
                           project_task_list.ListName,
                           project_task_list.ListStartDate,
                           project_task_list.ListEndDate,
                           project_task_list.ListStatusId,
                           project_task_list.ListSortOrder
                       } into group_result

                       select new ProjectTaskListModel
                       {
                           ListId = group_result.Key.ListId,
                           ProjectId = group_result.Key.ProjectId ?? 0,
                           ListName = group_result.Key.ListName,
                           ListStartDate = group_result.Key.ListStartDate,
                           ListEndDate = group_result.Key.ListEndDate,
                           ListStatusId = group_result.Key.ListStatusId ?? 0,
                           ListSortOrder = group_result.Key.ListSortOrder ?? 0,

                           ListTasksEstimatedHours = group_result.Sum(x => x.project_task.TaskEstimatedHours) ?? 0,
                           ListTasksTimeLogTotalMinutes = group_result.Sum(x => x.project_task_timelog.LogMinutes) ?? 0
                       };
```